# Graphical link moving algorithm

Tags: svg, draw

In order to develop a SVG drawing software, I would like to know if there is some algorithms to perform a moving of angular link between two rectangle. Angular link means a not linear link between two graphical objects, with a 90° angle.

Visual paradigm and others modelisation software perform nice moving of this type of link but I don't know how.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I believe that type of [graph layout algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing), is called "orthogonal layout".
Hopefully this will help you in your search.